# Are GX12 connectors in common use? Is there another name for them?

Tags: connector, design

I have a project where I need to send NeoPixel data from an RPI "base station" to a neopixel art project. Both the base station and the art project are enclosed already.

Length is short, just a few feet.

I could just use a 3.5 mm connector, but that seems like a poor design choice as they are overwhelmingly used for audio signals. They can also short tip and ring to sleeve when inserted hot.

From googling a bit, I found the GX12 connector. These look really cool, sort of an industrial / steampunk type vibe.

However, I couldn't find these on mouser.

Are they in common use? Is there another name for these? Does mouser sell them? Can I find them for relatively cheap in the USA? What is a good source for these parts?

Or perhaps you can recommend another connector? Panel mount, doesn't short, has a cool industrial feel, just need power, gnd, and signal.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic here. Maybe you could find a way to reword your question so that it isn't?